# Will 14.04 be using X.Org?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, mir

I heard that 13.10 used a mix of Mir and X.Org. How about 14.04? Will it also be using both or just Mir. If its just Mir then how do we get official (not proprietary) drivers to work (by AMD)

Comment: This is a question for http://discourse.ubuntu.com, not for AU!

Comment: @onrea Part--I think *most*--of this question seems concrete and objectively answerable. I've [tried to answer it appropriately](http://askubuntu.com/a/438855/22949).

Comment: In my opinion, this question is nowhere close to being a *bug report* or *problem* with the development version of Ubuntu. (It will also remain relevant when 14.04 is released... since people will still want to know if Mir has been adopted yet and whether or not traditional commercial drivers for their video cards will work, when contemplating adopting 14.04.)

Comment: @EliahKagan but it's speculation. We are not a news site, nor a gossip one. If anyone wants to know what will bring 14.04 either read the news/blogs or wait until release. And once 14.04 gets released, this question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Braiam The question what software is in 14.04 does not become irrelevant once 14.04 is released! (Also, the question of what software *is running in default 14.04 installations now* isn't one of speculation.)

Comment: @EliahKagan until 14.04 is released, the final release, nobody knows. This is the same as systemd/upstart, and any other piece of software, which is said to change in 14.04 but still the beta uses upstart. **We are not a news site**, the decisions can change in last minute. We are not supposed to start doing guesses on what road will take the development path. Is about using Ubuntu, not reading the future AU is for.

Comment: Thanks for the "this question doesnt belong on this website". Thats right ill just go to another site, spend 10 minutes signing up to post a singular simple question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

X.org continues to be packaged for 14.04 Trusty Tahr, as evidenced by [the `xorg` source package's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg) (showing package version 1:7.7+1ubuntu8 in Trusty) and the [`xserver-xorg` binary package's Ubuntu Packages database page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xserver-xorg). The [file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/xserver-xorg/filelist) shows it's not just a transitional package, but actually provides software--in particular, the `/usr/bin/X` executable.

Also, I'm currently running Trusty on a VMware virtual machine and when I log in to a Unity desktop, `/usr/bin/X` is running:

```
ek@Gnar:~$ ps ax | grep `pgrep Xorg` | head -1
 2494 tty7     Ss+    0:04 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

And this executable is provided by the `xserver-xorg` binary package, on my system:

```
ek@Gnar:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/X
xserver-xorg: /usr/bin/X
```

(To reproduce this, one may perform those steps or one may choose to look for `/usr/bin/Xorg` from `xserver-xorg-core` instead.)

And for additional assurance that X.org is still present in Ubuntu 14.04 *and remains the default display server*:

1. As [cited in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28display_server%29#Ubuntu), it was [at one time intended](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-June/037401.html) that Mir fully replace X.org in 14.04, but this [was postponed and is expected for Ubuntu 16.04 instead](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/mir-default-display-server-ubuntu-2016). See also [this article summarizing the history](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/11/stability-first-ubuntus-mir-wont-replace-x-in-14-04-desktop/).
2. Although [you can run Mir with a preview version of Unity 8 in 14.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/unity-8-desktop-preview-session-14-04), this version of Unity is provided by a separate package (`unity8-desktop-session-mir`) from the regular `unity` package. The Unity (major) version in 14.04 remains 7. Here's the [`unity` source package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity) and [the `unity` binary package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity).

   Or if you prefer to check from a 14.04 system, running `apt-cache policy unity` yields:

   ```
   unity:
     Installed: 7.1.2+14.04.20140321-0ubuntu1
     Candidate: 7.1.2+14.04.20140321-0ubuntu1
     Version table:
    *** 7.1.2+14.04.20140321-0ubuntu1 0
           500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

   Unity 7 uses X.org on Ubuntu.
3. As of this writing, 14.04 [has entered its final beta freeze](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2014-March/001093.html). At this point, improvement of 14.04 consists mainly of fixing bugs. Huge new features are extremely unlikely to be added.

As may be part of your motivation for asking this question, it's true there have been some concerns about driver support for Mir, with at least one major video vendor (Intel) [having said they don't plan to support it](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ1NjY). But X.org and Mir aren't the only display servers. In particular, it appears the [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) project (the Ubuntu flavor with KDE as the default desktop environment) [will be trying to adopt Wayland](http://web.archive.org/web/20130629223624/http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Kubuntu-plans-to-steer-clear-of-Mir-and-switch-to-Wayland-1897942.html). Wayland [already has significant support in commercial video drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29#Adoption).

Rather than speculate wildly about what *might* happen, I want to limit the focus of this answer to what *has* happened, been developed, and been announced. (More subjective or speculative answers, or forum-like discussion, would be more appropriate on Discuss. Credit to [onrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/152405/onrea) for [suggesting that site](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/).) But you may find useful information and news in some of the citations within [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28display_server%29#Controversy) of [the Wikipedia article on Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28display_server%29).

Comment: The conclusion of the OMGUbuntu editor, that Mir will be the default for 16.04 seems to me a bit far fetched. He is citing *"By 16.04 it’ll be the default display server…That’s the kind of timeline we’re looking at."* and making it sound like it will not happen earlier in non-LTS releases, while this is obvious for LTS releases, it is not set in stone. I personally wouldn't link to this poorly written (quote is [altered](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWTVe5Mdv0Y&feature=share&t=29m57s)), speculative and non-newsworthy story, but directly to the video.